# Sony Xperia Z1 - Camera Module Datasheet

Tags: datasheet

I'm writing to inquire about technical data related to the Sony IMX220 image sensor, as found in the camera module of the Xperia Z1.

I will be interfacing with the module and require a datasheet including timing information, registers, etc; is this data publically available? Thanks for any assistance with this matter.

Answer (score 2):

You need an nda with Sony to get that one.  Most high resolution camera sensors are under nda with their respective vendors.

They also have to be interested in your project so you may get no traction if it's just a home project or small commercial one.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I'm in touch with the Sony developers now; here's hoping they see merit in my project :)